# How to use faker.js in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, faker

As in topic. I cannot handle it :/
I've installed `npm i faker` and also `npm i @types/faker --save-dev`

my IDE found `fakerStatic.name.findName()` but browser not recognizes `fakerStatic`.

`import 'faker';` does not help.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to import it like:

```
import * as faker from 'faker';
```

And use it like:

```
faker.name.findName()
```

Comment: Works but got another problem `faker.locale = 'pl';` gives error `Cannot assign to 'locale' because it is a constant or a read-only property.`

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. [`locale` is not defined as read-only/const in the definition files.](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/faker/index.d.ts#L10). Try posting a new question?

Comment: @piernik Did you solve that issue? I'm getting the same message despite it not being defined as read-only/const.

Comment: @AndyJ @piernik you specify the locale in the import. Try `import * as faker from "faker/locale/pl";`

Comment: @MichaelSchnerring Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and get another error. I assume it must be something to do with my development environment. Really, I should post this all as a new question with the relevant info as Saravana suggested!

Comment: @AndyJ for me all I needed to do was importing it like that. Setting  `faker.locale` is not required.

Comment: For me 
`import * as faker from 'Faker';` was required.

Comment: @AndyJ Did you figure this out? I'm getting the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51642159/65387

Comment: Hello, I added faker to my `devDependencies` in `package.json`. Did the import as mentioned and um using 
`const newUser = _.set(_.cloneDeep(user), 'key', faker.phone.phoneNumber);` but getting an error *Cannot find module 'faker'*

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](https://fakerjs.dev/guide/usage.html) now says:

```
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker'
```

If it is to be localized data, the desired locale can also be attached.

```
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker/locale/de'
```