# TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'faker/locale/en_CA'

Tags: typescript

I'm getting this error:

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'faker/locale/en_CA'. '.../myproject/node_modules/faker/locale/en_CA.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

With this code:

```
import * as faker from 'faker/locale/en_CA';
```

The thing is, I installed `@types/faker`, and I can see that `node_modules/@types/faker/index.d.ts` does in fact include:

```
declare module "faker/locale/en_CA" {
    export = fakerStatic;
}
```

So the module *has* been declared, but TS can't find it for some reason.

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "importHelpers": false,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": ["es2017","esnext.asynciterable"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "target": "es2018",
        "declaration": true,
        "types" : ["node"],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": false,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["types/*"]
        }
    },

    "files": [
        "src/main"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something?

---

Note that

```
import * as faker from 'faker';
```

Works perfectly fine.

Both VSCode and PhpStorm can find `'faker/locale/en_CA'` no problemo, it's just `tsc` that can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `"types" : ["node"]` from tsconfig.json.  According to [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types), that line is saying you don't want TypeScript to load types for any package other than `node`.

Comment: Yup. That did it. Thought I needed that. Maybe that was before I added `@types/node` to my project?  I guess add `@types/xxx` is the preferred way to do things then? Strange that it accepted the root "faker" package but not "faker/locale/en_CA" if it was only looking for "node".

Answer (score 2):

Four years later I got a similar error.

Updating to TypeScript 4.* helped.

See https://github.com/faker-js/faker/issues/606

Comment:  Just avoid the bad version of Faker if it's still floating around (https://fakerjs.dev/about/announcements/2022-01-14.html#i-heard-something-happened-what-s-the-tldr)